# How to CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX with Fluent NHibernate

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate, sql-server-2008, fluent-nhibernate

I want to create a non clustered but unique index on two columns.
I tried:

```
Map(x => x.Col1).Index("IX").UniqueKey("IX");
Map(x => x.Col2).Index("IX").UniqueKey("IX");
```

and got non-unique index and additional unique constraint (switching order doesn't help),

or:

```
Map(x => x.Col1).Index("IX").Unique();
Map(x => x.Col1).Index("IX").Unique();
```

and got non-unique index and 2 additional unique constraints (switching order doesn't help).

Is there a way to create only the index, but unique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I leave out the `.Index()` and just write

```
Map(x => x.Col1).UniqueKey("IX");
Map(x => x.Col2).UniqueKey("IX");
```

I get a unique nonclustered Index in SQL 2008 Express (R2) without any additional constraints. (At least that is displayed when I view the porperties in the SQL Management Studio.)

Comment: Thanks. This generates different SQL script, but the result is almost "identical". You get unique constraint and an additional unique index, instead of just unique index. More info in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978680/constraint-is-key-is-index-is-constraint)