# Moving history data from a database to another through SSIS package

Tags: sql-server

I have two databases, I want to move some history data from a fact table to another database, the destination table is exactly the same as the source table including all the constrains.

I use a `SSIS` package  to transfer the data as below:

1. first use OLE DB Source to select the data from the source for the required period.
2. load it to temp table using OLE DB Destination into the second database.
3. Then load it to the final table using Execute SQL Task

   but I get below error

> Error: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint
>   'PK__Financia__362B520524BEA57A'. Cannot insert duplicate key in
>   object 'Fact.FinancialTransactions'. The duplicate key value is
>   (100001         , 2010012, Dec 31 2010 12:00AM, 65, 88).

How do I get around this issue? I want to keep the constrains in the destination table.

Comment: You need to specify what the issue is. What *do* you want to do with the duplicate keys? Update the existing entry, create another one, ignore it? Are you copying data that has already been copied? In this case you can ignore the duplicates - in fact you shouldn't have copied them at all.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to add one more execute SQL task which disables the constraints for some time period.But problem is if you disable primary key,you cant do any operations on a table,so dropping also can be an option ,but recreating again will take time.So best option would be to fix the error  or rebuild your index by below

> ALTER TABLE t1 REBUILD WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON)

this will allow duplicates to be ignored.more info here.[Can I set ignore_dup_key on for a primary key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594193/can-i-set-ignore-dup-key-on-for-a-primary-key)

Comment: This doesn't preserve the constraint, it ignores it. Creating duplicate entries isn't a viable solution, especially for tables called "FinancialTransactions"

Comment: my answer asks gives user all options and asks him to evaluate

Comment: I have just ignored the PK. i.e removed it the PK.