# Why is this query generating a PK violation error?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

So I'm trying, in a single query, to only insert a row if it doesn't exist already.

My query is the following:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[users_roles] ([user_id], [role_id]) 
SELECT 29851, 1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[users_roles] WHERE user_id = 29851 AND role_id = 1)
```

Sometimes (very rarely, but still), it generates the following error:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_USERS_ROLES'. Cannot
>   insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.users_roles'. The duplicate
>   key value is (29851, 1).

`PK_USERS_ROLES` is `[user_id], [role_id]`. Here is the full SQL of the table's schema:

```
create table users_roles
(
    user_id int not null
        constraint FK_USERS_ROLES_USER
        references user,
    role_id int not null
        constraint FK_USERS_ROLES_USER_ROLE
        references user_role,
    constraint PK_USERS_ROLES
    primary key (user_id, role_id)
)
```

**Context**:

This is executed by a PHP script hosted on an Apache server, and "randomly" happens once out of hundreds of occurrences (most likely concurrency-related).

More info:

- `SELECT @@VERSION` gives:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4000.0 (X64)   Jun 28 2012
>   08:36:30      Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation     Enterprise Edition
>   (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack)

- SQL Server version: `SQL Server 2008 R2`
- Transaction Isolation level: `ReadCommitted`
- This is executed within an *explicit* transaction (through PHP statements, but I figure the end result is the same)

**Questions**:

- Could someone explain why/how this is happening?
- What would be an efficient way to safely insert in one go (in other words, in a single query)?
  I've seen other answers such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20971680/sql-server-insert-if-not-exist) but the solutions are meant for stored procedures.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, is the primary key on just `user_id`? If so, maybe they are also a member of a role other than `1`.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Sorry, forgot to specify `PK_USER_ROLES`, I've just editer the question. It's composed of `[user_id], [role_id]`.

Comment: Well, [I can't reproduce this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyCWU.png), so there must be something you're not telling us, or perhaps two different threads of the application are submitting the same query at the exact same time. What isolation level are you using? Why are you so opposed to stored procedures? They can actually help solve concurrency issues.

Comment: I would go for the MERGE statement, there's an example in [that SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34892729/4003419).  It's like an upsert without the 'up' and only the 'sert'.

Comment: 1) same insert is being executed twice (from the same connection) 2) there are more than one connection doing the same insert

Comment: @AaronBertrand This literally happens once out of hundreds of times, probably in a scenario where multiple requests are made at the same time. Those queries are executed by a PHP web script btw (I will also edit that into the question).

Comment: @LukStorms `MERGE` seems like overkill for this and still won't solve the issue. Also see https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/

Comment: Such errors are regular scenarios for multiple connections running. You must handle them in your code and report to user/do something else.

Comment: @Aaron Betrand And, nothing against stored procedures. I'm just stunned that this query can generate such an SQL error at all. If using a stored procedure was a way out, I wouldn't mind using them. I'd ideally like to understand the technical implications tho.

Comment: @are you running query as mentioned or using dynamic query?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Oh wow...  I would think merge would be less buggy by now.  Thanks for the insight.

Comment: @maulikkansara This is the exact query that is sent to the SQL Server db, many times a day.

Comment: `Transaction Isolation level: Serializable` - how did you get this? @Jeto

Comment: Do you have a serializable transaction that contains more than just *this statement*?

Comment: @IvanStarostin Actually, I asked our DB admin (who is also reading this and investigating on his own). It seems like if I run the [command posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1038184/965834), I get `ReadCommitted` though. I'll edit the post and make 100% sure it's right (right context and all), sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yes, other `SELECT`s are made on the same (explicit) transaction (one of them on table `users_roles`). The `INSERT` I posted is the only one that isn't a SELECT tho. Let me know if you'd like more details, I'll edit the post then.

Comment: Yes show the whole transaction, this is likely what is affecting your concurrency.

Answer (score 1):

Is this table truncated or the rows deleted in some moment? And how often? It makes sense to me that the rows should not be found in some moment, as you're running "insert if not exists", and in this moment two or more queries may hit the database to insert the same data... only one will... the other should do nothing if the row was inserted before its "not exists" look up, or fail if the row was inserted after the look up.

I have only an Oracle database right now to do some tests and I can reproduce this problem. My commit mode is explicit:

- Create the empty table, the unique constraint and grant select, insert to another user:

  ```
  CREATE TABLE just_a_test (val NUMBER(3,0));

  ALTER TABLE just_a_test ADD CONSTRAINT foobar UNIQUE (val);

  GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON just_a_test TO user2;
  ```
- DB session on user1:

  ```
  INSERT INTO just_a_test 
  SELECT 10 
  FROM DUAL 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM just_a_test 
    WHERE val = 10
  )
  ;

  -- no commit yet...
  ```
- DB session on user2:

  ```
  INSERT INTO user1.just_a_test 
  SELECT 10 
  FROM DUAL 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM user1.just_a_test 
    WHERE val = 10
  )
  ;


  -- no commit yet, the db just hangs til the other session commit...
  ```

So I commit the first transaction, inserting the row, and then I get the following error on user2 session:

```
"unique constraint violated"
*Cause:    An UPDATE or INSERT statement attempted to insert a duplicate key.
           For Trusted Oracle configured in DBMS MAC mode, you may see
           this message if a duplicate entry exists at a different level.
```

Now I rollback the second transaction and run again the same insert on user2 and now I get the following output:

```
0 rows inserted.
```

Probably your scenario is just like this one. Hope it helps.

**EDIT**

I'm sorry. You asked two questions and I answered only the `Could someone explain why/how this is happening?` one. So I missed `What would be an efficient way to safely insert in one go (in other words, in a single query)?`.

What exactly means "safely" for you? Let's say you're running an INSERT/SELECT of lots of rows and just one of them is duplicated compared to the stored ones. For your "safety" level you should ignore all rows being inserted or ignore only the duplicated, storing the others?

Again, I don't have a SQL Server right now to give it a try, but looks like you can tell SQL Server whether to deny all rows being inserted in case of any dup  or deny only the dups, keeping the others. The same is valid for an insert of a single row... if it's a dup, throw an error... or just ignore it in the other hand.

The syntax should look like this to ignore dup rows only and throw no errors:

```
    ALTER TABLE [TableName] REBUILD WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON);
```

By default this option is OFF, which means SQL Server throws an error and discards non dup rows being inserted as well.

This way you would keep your INSERT/SELECT syntax, which looks good imo.

Hope it helps.

Sources:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-index-option-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2008

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11207687/1977836

Comment: Very interesting, thanks for your help. I'll look into this and get back to you.

Comment: @Jeto You're welcome. I just edited my answer and included a "solution" (looks more like a workaround). Hope it helps a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

It might help to be explicit about this. The below runs this in an explicit transaction, locks the row explicitly.

```
DECLARE @user_id INT; SET @user_id=29851;
DECLARE @role_id INT; SET @role_id=1;

BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    DECLARE @exists INT;
    SELECT @exists=1 
    FROM [dbo].[users_roles] WITH(ROWLOCK,HOLDLOCK,XLOCK)
    WHERE user_id=@user_id AND role_id=@role_id;

    IF @exists IS NULL
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[users_roles] ([user_id], [role_id])
        VALUES(@user_id,@role_id);
    END

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END CATCH
```

Comment: Thanks, we'll give this a try. Btw, seems like you deleted your above comment, I've tried answering them through an edit. Hard to figure which piece of info is relevant and which is not, sorry about that.

Comment: @Jeto I did delete that comment as you already updated your answer. The comment then becomes irrelevant. Note that with the version you have, you seem to be missing SP3 (see https://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com).

Comment: Sure, just letting you know in case you missed it. As for SP3 update, I'm not responsible for the DB server/platform itself but I'll see if we can get that.

Comment: @Jeto Did you gain any insights so far?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet. The DB server's administrator was busy all week and I'll be away from office for a few weeks, so won't be able to get back to it until then. Thank you for your help anyway (upvote was from me).