# Ignore/Remove duplicate rows in a column

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL table:

[image: table]

Table code:

```
CREATE TABLE Gender
(
GenderID int primary key identity,
Gender char(20)
)
```

I would like to ignore or remove duplicate rows in Gender, whilst maintaining the auto incrementation of GenderID (specified in my create table code), so that it results in:

```
----------------
|  1  |  Male  |
----------------
|  2  | Female |
----------------
```

My attempt:

```
DELETE
FROM Gender
WHERE GenderID NOT IN (
  SELECT MIN(GenderID)
  FROM Gender
  GROUP BY Gender)
```

Returns:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJleQ.png)

Comment: ----See edit----

Comment: And removing duplicates seems as easy as deleting any row where id > 2 and renaming id 2 to 'Female'? Or are you asking how to update foreign key records as well?

Comment: Attempt is up. Yeah GenderID is a foreign key to another table.

Comment: There is no row in the Gender table that has GenderID = 2 and Gender = 'Female'

Answer (score 0):

You can create new table and load the values as given below.

```sql
DECLARE @datasource TABLE(id int identity(1,1), gender CHAR(10))

INSERT INTO @datasource(gender)
SELECT * FROM 
(
VALUES
('male'),
('male'),
('male'),
('female'),
('female'),
('female')
) as t(gender)

SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT null)) as id, gender 
INTO NewTableName 
FROM @datasource
group by gender
```

**Result Set**

```
+----+-----------+
| id |  gender   |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | female    |
|  2 | male      |
+----+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you drop and re-create the table.
Add a unique index with IGNORE_DUP_KEY=ON to prevent duplicates.

[[Can I set ignore_dup_key on for a primary key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594193/can-i-set-ignore-dup-key-on-for-a-primary-key][1])